# Loop & filter in JSX. How can I reduce the number of loops in this situation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am in kind of the tricky situation where I never been before.

This thing is the customer want to control what to show and what not to show in `frontEnd` from the server.

What they give me in api is something look like this

```
let control = [
             {
                "Title": "Products",
                "Enable": true,
                "Icon": "",
                "Value": "3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Products",
                "Enable": true,
                "Icon": "",
                "Value": "3.1"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Bikes",
                "Enable": true,
                "Icon": "",
                "Value": "3.2"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Accessories",
                "Enable": true,
                "Icon": "",
                "Value": "3.3"
            },
            {
                "Title": "Components",
                "Enable": true,
                "Icon": "",
                "Value": "3.4"
            },
]
```

I told them to change the format but tell me back they can't change it. What they want is they want me to show the result accordingly to the ***Value*** of the return array.
I have already done the filtering but my code involve lots of looping.

Here is my code

```
{navigationList.length > 1 &&
              navigationList.map((data) => {
                {
                  return (
                    data.Value === '3' && (
                      <List.AccordionGroup>
                        <List.Accordion
                          style={styles.accordionStyle}
                          title="Products"
                          id="1">
                          {navigationList.map((data) => {
                            {
                              return (
                                data.Value === '3.1' && (
                                  <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={styles.drawerItemBorder}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                      props.navigation.navigate('ProductScreen')
                                    }>
                                    <Text
                                      style={styles.drawerItemBorderTextTwo}>
                                      Go to Products
                                    </Text>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                              );
                            }
                          })}

                          {navigationList.map((data) => {
                            {
                              return (
                                data.Value === '3.2' && (
                                  <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={styles.drawerItemBorder}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                      props.navigation.navigate('BikesScreen')
                                    }>
                                    <Text
                                      style={styles.drawerItemBorderTextTwo}>
                                      Bikes
                                    </Text>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                              );
                            }
                          })}

                          {navigationList.map((data) => {
                            {
                              return (
                                data.Value === '3.3' && (
                                  <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={styles.drawerItemBorder}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                      props.navigation.navigate(
                                        'AccessoriesScreen',
                                      )
                                    }>
                                    <Text
                                      style={styles.drawerItemBorderTextTwo}>
                                      Accessories
                                    </Text>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                              );
                            }
                          })}

                          {navigationList.map((data) => {
                            {
                              return (
                                data.Value === '3.4' && (
                                  <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={styles.drawerItemBorder}
                                    onPress={() =>
                                      props.navigation.navigate(
                                        'ComponentScreen',
                                      )
                                    }>
                                    <Text
                                      style={styles.drawerItemBorderTextTwo}>
                                      Components
                                    </Text>
                                  </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                              );
                            }
                          })}
                        </List.Accordion>
                      </List.AccordionGroup>
                    )
                  );
                }
              })}
```

So I want to know is what change I can make so that I can reduce the amount of looping here?

Comment: Why can't you sequentially map your control to JSX? Please share your expected JSX.

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or some other mechanism to transform the data into the format you need, e.g. group the items by value:

```js
const navigationList = [{
    "Title": "Products",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Products",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.1"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Bikes",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.2"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Accessories",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.3"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Components",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.4"
  },
];

const grouped = navigationList.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.Value] = [...acc[item.Value] || [], item]
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(grouped);
```

With the items grouped in this way you can then iterate them via [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to render the items in a single loop:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const navigationList = [{
    "Title": "Products",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Products",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.1"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Bikes",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.2"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Accessories",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.3"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Components",
    "Enable": true,
    "Icon": "",
    "Value": "3.4"
  },
];

const grouped = navigationList.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.Value] = [...acc[item.Value] || [], item]
  return acc;
}, {})

Object.entries(grouped).map(([value, items]) => {
  heading(value);
  items.map(i => item(i.Title))
})





// --------------------------------------------
// You can ignore everything below. It's dom manipulation utility
// stuff because running react/jsx in SO snippets is a hassle.

function e (content, tag = 'div') {
  const elem = document.createElement(tag);
  elem.innerHTML = content;
  return elem;
}

function heading(value) {
  container.appendChild(e(value, 'h2'));
}
function item(value) {
  container.appendChild(e(value));
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```